# What is wrong with this package declaration and definition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
package cpac 
as
  STGFILE xyz_INSTANCE.FILENAME%TYPE;
  procedure POC (cid     in xyz_instance.client_id%type, 
                 stgtype in xyz_instance.stg_instance%type, 
                 stgsrc  in xyz_instance.stg_source%type);
end;

package body cpac 
as
  procedure POC (cid     in xyz_instance.client_id%type, 
                 stgtype in xyz_instance.stg_instance%type, 
                 stgsrc  in xyz_instance.stg_source%type 
                 ) Is 
   BEGIN
      select filename 
        into stgfile 
        from xyz_instance 
       where stg_instance = stgtype 
         and stg_source = stgsrc 
         and client_id = cid;
   END POC;

begin
  POC('0123','19517','L');
  dbms_output.put_line(STGFILE); 
end cpac;
```

SQL statement alone is executing, procedure alone containing the SQL is also executing but only within the package i get error as :

> Error at line 4
>
> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement,

took reference from following document:http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch16_02.htm

Comment: Instead of just giving negative state whats wrong with the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the package header and body creation with `CREATE OR REPLACE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package cpac 
as
  STGFILE xyz_INSTANCE.FILENAME%TYPE;
  procedure POC (cid     in xyz_instance.client_id%type, 
                 stgtype in xyz_instance.stg_instance%type, 
                 stgsrc  in xyz_instance.stg_source%type);
end;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE package body cpac 
as
  procedure POC (cid     in xyz_instance.client_id%type, 
                 stgtype in xyz_instance.stg_instance%type, 
                 stgsrc  in xyz_instance.stg_source%type 
                 ) Is 
   BEGIN
      select filename 
        into stgfile 
        from xyz_instance 
       where stg_instance = stgtype 
         and stg_source = stgsrc 
         and client_id = cid;
   END POC;

begin
  POC('0123','19517','L');
  dbms_output.put_line(STGFILE); 
end cpac;
/
```

**EDIT**: if you don't have permission to create a package, then you can't create a package.  However, you may still be able to create a procedure or function within the `DECLARE` section of an anonymous PL/SQL block, and run the procedure/function later on during the block.  In the below sample I'm logged in as a user that doesn't have permissions to create a stored procedure, hence I get an error attempting to create one:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test as begin null; end;
  2  /
create or replace procedure test as begin null; end;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> DECLARE
  2     stgfile   xyz_instance.filename%TYPE;
  3
  4     procedure POC (cid     in xyz_instance.client_id%type,
  5                   stgtype in xyz_instance.stg_instance%type,
  6                   stgsrc  in xyz_instance.stg_source%type
  7                   ) Is
  8     BEGIN
  9        select filename
 10          into stgfile
 11          from xyz_instance
 12         where stg_instance = stgtype
 13           and stg_source = stgsrc
 14           and client_id = cid;
 15     END POC;
 16
 17  begin
 18    POC('0123','19517','L');
 19    dbms_output.put_line(STGFILE);
 20  end;
 21  /
test-filename.txt

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: do not have exclusive privileges to create or replace, just wanted to create a temporary package.

Comment: @Prashant: 'Temporary package'?  There's no such thing as a temporary package.

Comment: So, you mean we cannot have a package until we have privileges to create them.

Comment: @Prashant: yes.  If you don't have the privilege to create a package, you cannot create a package.

Comment: @Prashant: if you don't have the privileges to create a package, you also won't have the privileges to create stored procedures and functions.  However, you might still be able to create procedures and/or functions inside anonymous PL/SQL blocks.  (They aren't 'stored' procedures/functions as they 'temporary' and are discarded once the block finishes executing.) I've edited my answer to include a demonstration of this.